# why does the statements inside loop condition execute when condition is false in c programming?

Tags: c, loops, null

I am just running a code to find the length of a given string input by the user in C programming language. I used a loop condition to determine the length but statements inside loop executes when the condition is false also. The code  I have tried in c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ArrayLength 50

int StringLengthCount();

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    
    /*Question: Find inserted string's length, without build in function*/
    int c=StringLengthCount();
    printf("Your inserted string's length is:%d",c);


    return 0;
}

int StringLengthCount(){
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Please enter a sentence to find its length of character:");
    char array1[ArrayLength];
    fgets(array1,ArrayLength,stdin);
    printf("Your inserted string is:%s\n",array1);

    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    while(array1[i]!='\0'){
        count++;
        printf("%d character is %c",count,array1[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Your inserted string's total character i.e string length is:%d",count);
}
```

I am expecting the result 2 for a sample string input  "we", but it gives result 3.
The output result in CLion compiler is given below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agDJY.png)

Can you kindly tell me why it happens?

Comment: `count=i+1;` = `count++;` Your function is declared to return an int, but it doesn't. You don't even need `count`, because `i` is the length anyway.

Comment: I wanted to get string length without null character, but I am getting character length with null character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "statements inside loop executes when the condition is false also" you mean that you see an extra character every time you execute remember that also the line feed (LF alias `\n`) character that you use to enter your string is part of the acquired string.

So even the empty string has one character that is `\n` or `0x10`.

Your check should be something like this:

```
while (array1[len] != '\0' && array1[len] != '\n' )
```

And you function, as suggested in the comments, should have a return and could use just one variable like this:

```
int StringLengthCount() {

  printf("\n");
  printf("Please enter a sentence to find its length of character:");
  char array1[ArrayLength];
  fgets(array1, ArrayLength, stdin);
  printf("Your inserted string is:%s\n", array1);

  int len = 0;
  while (array1[len] != '\0' && array1[len] != '\n' ) {
    printf("%d character is %c", len + 1, array1[len]);
    printf("\n");
    len++;
  }

  printf("\n");
  printf("Your inserted string's total character i.e string length is:%d\n\n",
         len);

  return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have noted your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The function `fgets` will also read the newline character, so you need to change the condition in the while-loop from `str[i] != '\0'` to `str[i] != '\n'`. I have also implemented the suggested changes by [Devolus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282011/devolus).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 50

void string_length();

int main(void)
{
    string_length();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void string_length(void)
{
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    char str[LEN];
    fgets(str, LEN - 1, stdin);
    printf("Your entered string is: %s\n", str);

    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\n') {
        printf("The %d. character is '%c'.\n", i + 1, str[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    printf("\nThe string's length is %d.\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now understand the problems.